# Autoforms in MDriven

Tags: mdriven

[image]

I am using the Autoforms feature in MDriven and wonder if it limited to only allow one level of nesting, that is does it allow for multiple (using several multilinks) "EmbedInDocument", I only get it in "One level" (in pic below, I set this attribute on both "WorkOrderJob" and on "WorkOrderLine". Should both then be embedded in one VM (rooted in Workorder)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The AutoForms feature can follow many multi-links, but only one "level" deep. Otherwise I fear that it would be to complex and the created autoforms would risk being to large.

So, take ownership of the Autoform and extend it according to you needs.